# Power BI SQL Connection

Tags: powerbi-desktop, sqldb

I have a Power BI desktop report which extracts data from the database server through SQL.
Once complete, is it possible for me to **disconnect the SQL DB connection** but retain the data already extracted in the tables (of course, without further refresh). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes,once you import the data it will get saved with pbix file.